# JSON response getting null some time some time not

Tags: android, json, nullpointerexception

I am working on an android project .There is JSON response . but some time JSON shows response but some time it shows null. what may be reason . please provide solution . i have stuck in this last two days .

Comment: Where exactly you get NPE? From where do you get JSON response? Please post code.

Comment: try calling your api first from a testing tool, to make sure stuff works. curl or RestClient (for firefox) will help a lot.

Comment: I am  getting NPE when i am trying to show response.

Comment: Maybe the response is indeed null.